# How to report results from eight paired t-tests in a scientific paper?

Tags: data-visualization, t-test, reporting

What would be the most efficient way to report test results from several paired t-tests in a scientific paper? If I gave a bar graph per test result (something like [this](http://abacus.bates.edu/~ganderso/biology/resources/writing/HTWGREX4.gif)) would it be too much? Should I do a table instead? Or both? Give graphs only for the 'best' results?

Comment: If you hadn't to adjust for multiplicity, graphs only for the best results are highly discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, a table of numeric results (p-values, t statistics and Confidence Intervals for the means of the differences) would be necessary. I would suggest to add a graph with the Confidence Intervals for the means of the differences, something like [this](http://understandinguncertainty.org/files/premier-confints_0.png). Or maybe a paired bar plot like [this one](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/images/econ_cin557_1.gif). It depends so much on what's the point you are trying to prove.

Anyhow, it's allways a good strategy to search similar papers (better if in the same journal you want to publish) and follow their lead (as long as you don't detect some error or something that could be improved).